# Как написать на C# свой HtmlHelpers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

Хочу сделать свои HtmlHelper, но так что бы первый екстеншен, после Html, был мой, а после этого уже HtmlHelper, как в Kendo.

```
Пример:
     @(Html.MyExtensions().TabStrip()
        .Name("tabs")
        .Collapse(true)
        )
```

Создал для этого клас HTMLHelperExtension и сделал метод расширения на клас HtmlHelper где мето возвращает клас

```
    public static class HTMLHelperExtension
    {
         public static TabsExtensions MyExtensions(this HtmlHelper @this)
         {
            return new TabsExtensions();
         }
    }

 public class TabsExtensions
    {
        public TabsExtensions TabStrips()
        {
            return new TabsExtensions();
        }
    }
```

После этого сделал класс TabStrip где методы Name(), Collapsible() росширяют клас TabsExtensions

```
 public static class TabStrip
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Name(this TabsExtensions @this, string name)
    {
        .................................. 
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString Collapsible(this TabsExtensions @this, bool collapsible)
    {
        ..................................
    }
}
```

Проблема вот в чем, я могу использовать только один метод расширения или Name или Collapsible.

```
@(Html.MyExtensions().TabStrip()
        .Name("tabs")
        .Collapse(true) <-----этот метод уже не работает
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из метода Name вы возвращаете MvcHtmlString, а метод Collapse принимает на вход TabsExtensions. Возвращайте всегда TabsExtensions из ваших методов расширений и тогда получится вызывать их цепочкой. И добавьте один метод, который из сконфигурированных TabExtensions генерировать строку.

```
 public static class TabStrip
 {
     public static TabsExtensions Name(this TabsExtensions @this, string name)
     {
           // заменен возвращаемый тип
        .................................. 
     }

    public static TabsExtensions Collapse(this TabsExtensions @this, bool collapsible)
     {
           // заменен возвращаемый тип
         ..................................
     }

     public static MvcHtmlString Render(this TabsExtensions @this)
     {
             return @this.RenderString(); -- здесь может быть любой другой код, который генерирует строку, это приведён как пример
     }
 }
```