# C# fluent interface(цепочные интерфейсы),Custom HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, razor, fluent-interface

Продолжение темы [fluent interface](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/835874/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-htmlhelpers/835882#835882)

Для реализации своего HTMLHelper

Пример:

```
@(Html.ExExtensions().TabStrip()
        .Name("tabs")
        .Collapse(true)
        .Text("Some text")
        .Items(
               item=>{
                      .Add().Text("Tab 1").Selected(true).Content("Content tab 1");
                      .Add().Text("Tab 2").Content("Content tab 2");
                     }
              )
 )
```

Этот рендерится в такой HTML код:

```
<section id="tabs" class="collapsible">
<h2>Some text</h2>
<div class="collapsible-content">
    <div class="tabstrip">
        <div class="triggers">
            <span class="trigger active">Tab 1</span>
            <span class="trigger">Tab 2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs">
            <div class="tab">Content tab 1</div>
            <div class="tab">Content tab 2t</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Есть 3 класса:
ExHTMLHelperExtension класс в кором метод ExExtensions расширяет класс HtmlHelper

```
 public static class ExHTMLHelperExtension
{
    public static ExExtensions SFX(this HtmlHelper @this)
    {
        return new ExExtensions();
    }
}
```

Второй класс ExExtensions

```
 public class ExExtensions
{
    public ExExtensions TabStrip()
    {
        return new ExExtensions();
    }
}
```

Третий класс TabStrip

```
 public static class TabStrip
{
    private static string TabStripName { get; set; }

    private static bool TabStripCollapsible { get; set; }

    private static string TabStripText { get; set; }

    private static TagBuilder TagBuilder { get; set; }

    private static Action<ItemTabs> ItemTabs { get; set; }


    public static ExExtensions Name(this ExExtensions @this, string name)
    {
        Ensure.IsNotNullOrEmpty(name, nameof(name));

        TabStripName = name;
        return new SFXExtensions();
    }

    public static ExExtensions Collapsible(this ExExtensions @this, bool collapsible)
    {
        TabStripCollapsible = collapsible;
        return new SFXExtensions();
    }

    public static ExExtensions Text(this ExExtensions @this, string text)
    {
        Ensure.IsNotNullOrEmpty(text, nameof(text));

        TabStripText = text;
        return new SFXExtensions();
    }


    public static ExExtensions Items(this ExExtensions @this, Action<ItemTabs> itemTabs)
    {
        Ensure.IsNotNull(itemTabs, nameof(itemTabs));
        ItemTabs = itemTabs;
        return new SFXExtensions();
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString Render(this ExExtensions @this)
    {
        var tagSection = new TagBuilder("section");
        var tagDiv = new TagBuilder("div");
        var tagTab = new TagBuilder("div");
        if (TabStripName.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            tagSection.Attributes.Add("id", TabStripName);
        }

        if (TabStripText.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            var tagText = new TagBuilder("h2");
            tagText.SetInnerText(TabStripText);
            tagSection.InnerHtml += tagText.ToString();
        }

        if (!TabStripCollapsible)
        {
            tagSection.Attributes.Add("class", "collapsible");
            tagDiv.AddCssClass("collapsible-content");
            tagSection.InnerHtml += tagDiv;

        }

        if (ItemTabs!=null)
        {
            tagTab.AddCssClass("tabstrip");
            ItemTabs = tabs => tabs.Render();
            ItemTabs(new ItemTabs());
            tagTab.InnerHtml += ItemTabs;
        }
        new MvcHtmlString(tagTab.ToString());

        return new MvcHtmlString(tagSection.ToString());
    }
}
```

Метод Render собирает методы и рендерит Html код.
Есть метод Items где должно рендерится количество табов в блоке div с классом tabstrip.
Для реализации екстеншен методов в методе Items- создал класс ItemTabs

```
public class ItemTabs
{
    private string TriggersText { get; set; }

    private bool TriggerSelected { get; set; }

    private string TabContent { get; set; }

    private TagBuilder TagTrigger => new TagBuilder("div");

    private TagBuilder TagTab=> new TagBuilder("div");

    public ItemTabs Add()
    {
        TagTrigger.AddCssClass("trigger");
        return this;
    }

    public ItemTabs Text(string text)
    {
        TriggersText = text;
        TagTrigger.InnerHtml += TriggersText;
        return this;
    }

    public ItemTabs Selected(bool selected)
    {
        TriggerSelected = selected;
        TagTrigger.AddCssClass("active");
        return this;
    }

    public ItemTabs Content(string htmlString)
    {
        TabContent = htmlString;
        TagTab.AddCssClass("tab");
        TagTab.InnerHtml += TabContent;

        return this;
    }

    public void Render()
    {
        new MvcHtmlString(TagTrigger.ToString());
        new MvcHtmlString(TagTab.ToString());
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что страница рендерится только до блока с классом collapsible-content- внутри этого блока больше ничего нету. Не могу  разобраться!